# Testing items in a tokenlist variable for special characters using tokenlist constants

Tags: expl3

My attempts to test individual items in a tokenlist variable for special characters using the constants provided in `interface3 VII.9: Constant token lists` are failing miserably. Passing a special character as an argument, loading it into a variable, and then making the comparison works fine. But as for getting the syntax right using the constants - failure. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 17 November 2018
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\myTestTokenlist{mO{\#}}
    {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
      \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {#2}
      \textbf{\#1~argument~received:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl\\
      \textbf{\#2~argument~received:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl\\
      Compare~variables:~
      \tl_if_eq:NNTF  \l_rn_auxOne_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
        {\textbf{match}\\}
        {\textbf{NO~match}\\}
      Test~for~\str_use:N \c_hash_str :~
      % Testing for specific special characters using the string constants
      % \c_ampersand_str, \c_atsign_str, \c_backslash_str, etc. returns consistently
      % the FALSE result
      \tl_if_eq:NNTF  \l_rn_auxOne_tl \c_hash_str 
        {\textbf{match}\\}
        {\textbf{NO~match}\\}
    }   %   \myTestTokenlist
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\verb+\myTestTokenlist{\#}+\\
\myTestTokenlist{\#}

\verb+\myTestTokenlist{\$}[\textbackslash]+\\
\myTestTokenlist{\$}[\textbackslash]

\verb+\myTestTokenlist{\$}[\$]+\\
\myTestTokenlist{\$}[\$]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\#` is not the `#` character, nor is `\$` a `$` character.

Comment: Well, the plot thickens!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run from the shell

```
latexdef \#
```

the answer is

```
\#:
\char"23
```

Indeed `latex.ltx` defines `\#` with `` \chardef\#=`\# ``. Thus

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl { \# }
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxTwo_tl { \# }
\tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_rn_auxOne_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
```

obviously returns true, but

```
\tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_rn_auxOne_tl \c_hash_str
```

returns false. For `\$` and `\textbackslash` it is even more complicated, because `\$` expands to

```
\x@protect\$\protect\$
```

and `\textbackslash` to

```
\OMS-cmd \textbackslash \OMS\textbackslash
```

Leaving aside the issue with the meaning, a token list containing `\#` and `\c_hash_str` are very different things to begin with.

Comment: Your explanations are providing me with a glimpse of unfathomable depths. Rather unsettling, but I'll see where it takes me with a concrete practical problem I have. For now, if `\# is \char"23`, where do I find the definitions of other `special characters` like `\&`, `\%`, etc. ?  This may lead to a separate question in due course.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth `\&` and `\%` are `\chardef` tokens like `\#`. But `\{\}\_` are in the same group as `\$`. Essentially, there is no choice for printing `\#\&\%`, but the others have to be defined in a special way for typesetting purposes (a source of the problem is the fact that the original OT1 font encoding uses some slots for other glyphs than the corresponding ASCII characters)..