# Testing a tl variable for being a special character

Tags: expl3

Following on from my question yesterday ([Testing items in a tokenlist variable for special characters using tokenlist constants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460426/)) and the brief discussion and answer I had from egreg, the least I would have hoped for is that the MWE below returns a match, but no luck. What is wrong with my syntax here?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 18 November 2018
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\myTestTokenlist{m}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxOne_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxTwo_tl {\char"23}
    \textbf{\#1~argument~received:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl\\
    \textbf{special~character:}~\tl_use:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl\\
    Compare~variables:~
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_rn_auxOne_tl \l_rn_auxTwo_tl
      {\textbf{match}\\}
      {\textbf{NO~match}\\}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\verb+\myTestTokenlist{\#}+\\
\myTestTokenlist{\#}

\verb+\myTestTokenlist{\$}+\\
\myTestTokenlist{\$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the results of `\tl_show:N \l_rn_auxOne_tl
    \tl_show:N \l_rn_auxTwo_tl`. You will see that they are *not* equal, so the comparison will fail. Concerning the reason I would make the wild guess that `\#` is not expanded to its definition of `\char`.

Comment: `\#` is a “chardef token”, so it is unexpandable and it is `\ifx`-equal to another token if and only if the other token is a “chardef token” pointing to the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460429/4427), `\#` is defined via `\chardef`. Such a token is therefore *unexpandable*.

If used in a typesetting context, it will output the character in the current font corresponding to the given number (hexadecimal `0x23` or decimal 35 for `\#`). If used where TeX is looking for a number, it will produce the number: the test `\ifnum\#="23` will return true.

TeX's token comparison rules are clear in this case: `\#` and `\char"23` are different token lists for several reasons. First and foremost, the former is one token long, the latter is four token long.

Can you do `\tl_set:Nx \l_rn_auxOne_tl {\#}` and compare `\l_rn_auxOne_tl` with a token list containing `\char"23`? Yes, but the test will return false, because `\#` is unexpandable and so using `x`-expansion does nothing to it.

You could use a composite test:

```
\bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \token_if_chardef_p:N \# } { \int_compare_p:n { \# = "23 } }
 {Found \token_to_str:N \#}
 {Not found \token_to_str:N \#}
```

Example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testtoken}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF { #1 }
   {% only one token
    \rn_test_single:N #1
   }
   {
    --several~tokens~given,~retry.--
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \rn_test_single:N
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF 
   { \token_if_chardef_p:N #1 }
   { \int_compare_p:n { #1 = "23 } }
   { Found~\texttt{\token_to_str:N \#} }
   { Not~found~\texttt{\token_to_str:N \#} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\testtoken{abc}

\testtoken{#}

\testtoken{\%}

\testtoken{\#}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me it's not clear what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[check-declarations,log-functions]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxi_tl
\tl_new:N \l_rn_auxii_tl

\NewDocumentCommand \myTestTokenlist { m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxi_tl {#1}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxii_tl {\#}
  \textbf{\#1 ~ argument ~ received:} ~ \texttt{\tl_to_str:N \l_rn_auxi_tl} \\
  \textbf{special ~ character:} ~ \texttt{\tl_to_str:N \l_rn_auxii_tl} \\
  Compare ~ variables: ~
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_rn_auxi_tl \l_rn_auxii_tl
   { \textbf{match} \par }
   { \textbf{NO ~ match} \par }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verb+\myTestTokenlist{\#}+\\
\myTestTokenlist{\#}

\verb+\myTestTokenlist{\$}+\\
\myTestTokenlist{\$}

\end{document}
```

If you want to compare `\#` to something, compare it to `\#`, I don't know why do you write `\char"23` which is obviously different. Your program compares what the token list *has*, not that it *outputs* something equal.

If you want to compare `#` you can, but you need to take into account that when inside a command definition you have to double the `#`s. This would work:

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxi_tl {#}
\tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxii_tl {#}
\tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_rn_auxi_tl \l_rn_auxii_tl
 { match }
 { no ~ match }
```

but since you are inside a macro definition you need to double the `##`

```
\NewDocumentCommand \testtokenlist { m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxi_tl {#1}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_rn_auxii_tl {##}
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_rn_auxi_tl \l_rn_auxii_tl
   { match }
   { no ~ match }
 }
```

and then `\testtokenlist{#}`.

But you should explan what you want, because I don't see a precise logic here. May be you should consider `\str_if_eq:` instead of `\tl_if_eq:`?

Comment: I will provide the context for what, at this stage, appears a senseless exercise, a little later.